# Curious if statement behavior

Tags: java, android

Anyone care to explain this?

```
public Overlay hitTest(float x, float y) {
    boolean hit = x >= bounds.left && x <= bounds.right
            && y >= bounds.top && y <= bounds.bottom;
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, getId() + (hit ? "" : " not ") + " hit");
    if (hit) return this;
    return null;
}
```

This always returns null. Even when `hit` is `true`. The Logcat prints exactly what it should for items objects that are hit and not hit. Really scratching my head...

I must be doing something really dim, but I can't figure out what. And I apologize if there is already a topic on this, but this is a surprising hard search topic.

Comment: What makes you think it's always returning null? It probably isn't.

Comment: The debugger, it steps to the return null line. This is the latest iteration. I've tried it with a explicit else an it still steps into the else.

Comment: The only times I've seen strange behavior that i couldn't explain is when my IDE gets confused. Maybe the code in the IDE and the device are not the same. So stupid response time... Make sure you clean your project files, rebuild and redeploy everything.

Comment: Gene wins the prize. It actually isn't returning `null` stepping out show the correct object (and when I fixed the other boneheaded mistakes the rest of the program works).  Android studios just places the cursor at the wrong line. Thanks.

Comment: @seiterm please make that an answer and then accept it so that people know your problem has been solved.

Comment: I can't accept it for two more days, but I've added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with how Android Studio moved the debug cursor. The logic is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the Log.d call may be stepping on the stack (aka smashing the stack) and setting hit to false. I have written Java code that stepped on the stack and had similar hard to debug problems.

Comment: The `Log.d` was added when it started to misbehave. Without the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the second line logic inverted?

```
 && y >= bounds.top && y <= bounds.bottom;
```

It seems to me that that line should be as the follow

```
 && y <= bounds.top && y >= bounds.bottom;
```

Comment: Nope. Android graphics reckons the top left as the origin. btw: read the comments before answering. The answer is there (there never really was a problem). If I was meaner I'd down vote this answer.